# How to add security to the remoteEntry.js in module federation webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-module-federation

I'm using module federation to implement Micro Front-End. The remoteEntry.js generated by the micro apps are consumed by the container application and it works fine.

**The Question is:**

https://app1.example.com/remoteEntry.js
is consumed by the shell app but this could also be consumed by anyone with this url.
How can I restrict only the shell app, or a set of apps could access this script and not others.